# Question about an answer related to designing an ASM for a sequence detector

Tags: finite-automata

The question says:

> Design a sequence detector that searches for a series of binary inputs to satisfy
> the pattern 01[0*]1, where [0*] is any number of consecutive zeroes. The
> output (Z) should become true every time the sequence is found.

The answer to this example in the document I am reading is this:

[image]

My question is: After going from state 'first', the decision box checks X. If it is 0, then it does not fit the pattern 01[0*]1. So, it should go back to state 'start'. In this answer, it goes back to state 'first' instead, and so a sequence that violates the pattern could eventually get accepted. For example, the sequence 0011 does not match the pattern given, yet it will be accepted by the given ASM. The first 0 will land us in state 'first', and the 2nd 0 will go back to 'first' and then the 1 will lead to state 'second' and the final one will go to state 'success', outputting Z.

Am I correct to think so? If not, why?

The document can be found here: https://www.mil.ufl.edu/3701/classes/joel/17%20Lecture.pdf

The question is tagged with finite automata because there is no ASM tag. The two are similar enough.

Comment: Can you find a specific sequence that violates the pattern but would eventually get accepted?  I suggest you try to find one.  That either might enable you to answer your own question, or to add more specifics to the question.

Comment: @D.W. The simplest I can think of is 0011. I will add it as an example of an invalid sequence to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  It looks like this accepts 0011, and it shouldn't, so it looks to me like the automaton is buggy.